# Failure to find getChildren(), following official Oracle guide to JavaFX WebKit

Tags: java, javafx, webkit, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm exactly following example 3 from [this Oracle guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm), and compiling with Maven. Here's the entire code (just two classes), and the error that I get.

```
package com.anon.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import com.anon.example.Browser;

public class Example extends Application
{
    private Scene scene;

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        stage.setTitle("WebKit Example");

        scene = new Scene(new Browser(), 750, 500, Color.web("#666970"));

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}

package com.anon.example;

import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

class Browser extends Region
{
    final WebView browser   = new WebView();
    final WebEngine engine  = browser.getEngine();
    final String URL = "http://www.oracle.com/products/index.html";

    public Browser()
    {
        getStyleClass().add("browser");
        engine.load(URL);
        getChildren.add(browser);
    }

    private Node createSpacer()
    {
        Region spacer = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        return spacer;
    }

    @Override protected void layoutChildren()
    {
        double w = getWidth();
        double h = getHeight();
        layoutInArea(browser, 0, 0, w, h, 0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefWidth(double height)
    {
        return 750;
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefHeight(double width)
    {
        return 500;
    }
}
```

*Browser.java:[27,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable getChildren*

I'm stumped - getChildren() should be inherited from Region, which inherits it from Parent. Google turns up no answers. I realize the guide was written for JavaFX 2, but in this respect the API docs for 8 look no different. Any ideas?

Comment: can you post the more code.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the entire code.

Comment: Voting to close, as this doesn't really help solve any real problems, it was just a typo (which happens ;-) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
        getChildren().add(browser);
```

and not

```
        getChildren.add(browser);
```

Comment: Oh my god. Sorry, everyone.